# Can't change size and position for UIView loaded from xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

I have a `UICollectionView` and the dark grey area on the top. In this grey area I needed to put tabs with `UIView`. Because I'll need outlets, this `UIView` has its own `TabsViewController`. No matter what I do, the view I am trying to add is always stays in the top left corner with strange offset and size.

I tried to change it size and position or to put it on top of different views — it is always gives the same visual result.

Auto Layout is on. This view should have height of 72 and 100% width.

[image]

```
TabsViewController *tabs = [[TabsViewController alloc] init];
CGSize screen = // returns correct screen size
tabs.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screen.width, 72);
[self.collectionView addSubview:tabs.view];
```

I tried to call code above from multiple places, including `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: try this code in viewDidAppear()

Comment: @TejasArdeshna I tries it just now, it gives the same result. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the auto layout you have to change the constrains instead of frame.
Just connect your view constrains to code as [nslayoutconstrains](/questions/tagged/nslayoutconstrains) and try changing your constrains to set your view programatically.

Connect constraint of your view in IB to code as IBOutlet properties

Example :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *width;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *hieght;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topSpace;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *horizontalCenter;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftSpace;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *rightSpace;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *verticalCenter;
```

And change there values as:

```
self.width.constant=CURRENT_VALUE_FOR_CONSTRAINT;
self.hieght.constant=CURRENT_VALUE_FOR_CONSTRAINT;
self.topSpace.constant=CURRENT_VALUE_FOR_CONSTRAINT;
self.horizontalCenter.constant=CURRENT_VALUE_FOR_CONSTRAINT;
self.leftSpace.constant=CURRENT_VALUE_FOR_CONSTRAINT;
self.rightSpace.constant=CURRENT_VALUE_FOR_CONSTRAINT;
self.verticalCenter.constant=CURRENT_VALUE_FOR_CONSTRAINT;
```

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: I already defined all necessary constraints in the Interface Builder. Are you saying I need to set them again programmatically?

Comment: No just connect those constrains to code as IBOutlet

Comment: can you please show me an example how to do it? I never did "connect constraints" before.

Comment: I did as you said and it didn't changed anything. I can't see why it should. View which I'm trying to put on the top has its Auto Layout visible, you can see on the picture I attached — the one light-grey square tab is visible, it's also has correct height of 72. The position of this view is wrong, Auto Layout can not affect position. It also should stretch to entire width of the screen which I am trying to do with changing frame.